# phonegap Auto Send Gps Position to Mysql Server. Even application is not opened

Tags: android, mysql, cordova

i create aplication on android using phonegap/cordova. that will use by courier to deliver products. Their Android aplication will send gps coordinates to server every periodic/specific time automatically.

but my problem is : its only done well if i open the aplication. What can i ll do to make it run, even my android application is not opened.

this is my code

```
function onDeviceReady() 
    {
    var deviceID = device.uuid;
   localStorage.setItem('pinid',deviceID);
    var options = { frequency: 3000 }; //THIS I SPECIFY INTERVAL TIME TO SEND POSITIONS
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

function onSuccess(position) 
{

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
var get_pinid="";
var get_pinid=localStorage.getItem('pinid');

$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'&sensor=false', function(data) {
alamats = data.results[0];
localStorage.setItem('alrum',alamats.formatted_address);

});
var al="";
var al=localStorage.getItem('alrum');
    //SEND TO SERVER
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://www.domain.com/demo_android/set_position.php?",
     data: "addr=" +al+ "&langi="+ lat + "&longi="+ lng+ "&devi="+ get_pinid,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      }
    });


}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish your app as a "background service" by using the Cordova Background Services Plugin. This will allow your app to continue sending data even after the user moves on to using another app. The instructions for establishing your Cordova app as a service are located at:

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

I would include the actual instructions here, but it is quite a lengthy process and in this case, I think the most efficient and helpful answer is to provide a link to the project page which contains the instructions.

Let me know if I can be of any more help. Good luck!